# What is the reason of std::bad_alloc in that code?

Tags: c++

Recently i wrote that code and i noticed that somewhere here causing

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what():  std::bad_alloc`

Here is my code:

```
namespace logger {
    set<string> pendingLogs;
    bool isDebugEnabled = false;
    mutex logMutex;

    inline void add_log_to_pending(const string &text) {
        lock_guard<mutex> guard(logMutex);
        cout << "[Logger] Adding: " << text << endl;

        pendingLogs.insert(text);
    }

    inline string grab_logs() {
        string collector;
        lock_guard<mutex> guard(logMutex);
        if (pendingLogs.empty()) return collector;

        for (const auto& item: pendingLogs) {
            collector += item + "\n";
        }

        pendingLogs.clear();
        return collector;
    }
}
```

Starting thread code:

```cpp
std::thread log_composer_thread(&log_composer_callable);
log_composer_thread.detach();
```

Function thread code:

```
[[noreturn]] void log_composer_callable() {
    logger::log_debug("Log composer thread started..");
    while (true) {
        const string &logs = logger::grab_logs();
        if (logs.empty()) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
            continue;
        }

        //send logic
    }
}
```

What could cause that error here? I though that it's related with curl library but when i **disabled** whole logging logic, all errors disappeard so that's why i think error is somewhere in logger code

Edit 1:

```
inline std::vector<unsigned char>
rsa_encrypt_pubkey(EVP_PKEY *pubKey, unsigned char *toEncrypt, size_t toEncryptLength, bool eraseInputArray) {
    size_t outlen;
    if (toEncryptLength > 256) {
        logger::add_log_to_pending("Error: rsa_encrypt_pubkey: toEncryptLength > 256");
        return {};
    }

    //init the cipher context for encryption using the public key
    EVP_PKEY_CTX *enc_ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(pubKey, nullptr);
    EVP_PKEY_encrypt_init(enc_ctx);
    EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(enc_ctx, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);
    EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_oaep_md(enc_ctx, EVP_sha256());

    //determine output length
    if (!EVP_PKEY_encrypt(enc_ctx, nullptr, &outlen, toEncrypt, toEncryptLength)) {
        logger::add_log_to_pending("Error: EVP_PKEY_encrypt | " + string(ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr)));
        return {};
    }

    std::vector<unsigned char> encrypted(outlen);

#if debug_mode_advanced == 1
    cout << "Output length: " << outlen << " toEncryptLenght: " << toEncryptLength << endl;
    cout << ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr) << endl;
#endif

    //final encrypt call
    if (!EVP_PKEY_encrypt(enc_ctx, &encrypted[0], &outlen, toEncrypt, toEncryptLength)) {
        logger::add_log_to_pending("Error: EVP_PKEY_encrypt | " + string(ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr)));
        return {};
    }

    //clean up
    EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(enc_ctx);
    if (eraseInputArray) free(toEncrypt);

    return encrypted;
}
```

that code causing a problem, what could be the problem here?

Edit 2:

```cpp
inline vector<unsigned char>
rsa_encrypt_rewrite(unsigned char *in, size_t inlen, EVP_PKEY *key, bool eraseInputArray) {
    try {
        EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx;
        ENGINE *eng;
        unsigned char *out;
        size_t outlen;

        if (inlen > 256) {
            logger::add_log_to_pending("Error: rsa_encrypt_pubkey: toEncryptLength > 256");
            return {};
        }
        ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(key, eng);
        if (!ctx) {
            logger::add_log_to_pending(
                    "Error: EVP_PKEY_CTX_new | " + string(ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr)));
            return {};
        }
        /* Error occurred */
        if (EVP_PKEY_encrypt_init(ctx) <= 0) {
            logger::add_log_to_pending(
                    "Error: EVP_PKEY_encrypt_init | " + string(ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr)));
            return {};
        }
        /* Error */
        if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(ctx, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING) <= 0) {
            logger::add_log_to_pending(
                    "Error: EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding | " + string(ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr)));
            return {};
        }
        /* Error */

/* Determine buffer length */
        if (EVP_PKEY_encrypt(ctx, nullptr, &outlen, in, inlen) <= 0) {
            logger::add_log_to_pending(
                    "Error: EVP_PKEY_encrypt | " + string(ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr)));
            return {};
        }
        /* Error */

        out = (unsigned char *) OPENSSL_malloc(outlen);

        if (!out) {
            logger::add_log_to_pending("Error: OPENSSL_malloc");
            return {};
        }
        /* malloc failure */

        if (EVP_PKEY_encrypt(ctx, out, &outlen, in, inlen) <= 0) {
            logger::add_log_to_pending(
                    "Error: EVP_PKEY_encrypt | " + string(ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr)));
            return {};
        }

        EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx);
        if (eraseInputArray) free(in);

        vector<unsigned char> encrypted(out, out + outlen);
        OPENSSL_free(out);
        return encrypted;
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        logger::add_log_to_pending("Error: rsa_encrypt_rewrite general exception: " + string(e.what()));
        return {};
    }

}
```

Is that code seems to be ok? And bad_alloc shouldnt appear?

Comment: Out of memory?  error is caused by the whole app, not just by the code shown. Difficult to answer. Give a [mcve].

Comment: `const string &logs =` that seems off. It's a reference to a temporary object. Do you have compiler warnings enabled?

Comment: @JHBonarius It is unusal but fine. If the initializer is a prvalue expression as here, it will bind to the temporary and extend its lifetime to the scope of the reference.

Comment: @JHBonarius I didnt have any warnings about that

Comment: @JHBonarius i added try/catch to each of those function and i detected: "Error: in log_composer_callable reason std::bad_alloc"

Comment: Your debugger should provide some means of setting a generic breakpoint on `throw` expressions: `catch throw` in `gdb`.  That should allow you to 'home in' on the code causing the problem.  My guess would be that you're possibly trying to allocate a huge chuck due to a negative 'size' being interpreted as an unsigned value.

Comment: Where is the code that is calling `add_log_to_pending()`? And why are you using a `std::set` to collect logs, instead of using a `std::vector` or a `std::list`?

Comment: Maybe at some point a `std::string` is trying to reallocate or allocate in other process

Comment: @RemyLebeau why you think that vector/list would be better than set?

Comment: @G.M. well i would try with debugger but that error is very rare and i must use python script to run it like 10-500 times to get that error

Comment: If the problem is that intermittent it might suggest undefined behaviour elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Regarding Remy's comment on your use of `std::set`:  `std::set` will reorder your pending log strings meaning they will not be output in the order in which they were passed to `logger::add_log_to_pending`.

Comment: @G.M.but i'm almost sure that it's caused by logger because if i disabled logging, error didnt appear at all

Comment: @Kaspek If it *is* undefined behaviour then the program is ill-formed and almost anything can happen.  The fact that disabling logging eliminates the symptom is irrelevant.

Comment: Maybe sending logs blocks so more and more logs are pending and eventually you just run out of memory.

Comment: @Kaspek `std::set` is a *sorted* container of *unique* elements. It will re-order your logs, and drop duplicate logs. Is that what you really want? With `std::vector` or `std::list`, you will get back out everything you put in, and in the original order.

Comment: @G.M. i edited message, i found the code which caused a problem but i dont know what exactly here could be be problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue is in this part of the code:

```
if (!EVP_PKEY_encrypt(enc_ctx, nullptr, &outlen, toEncrypt, toEncryptLength)) {
    logger::add_log_to_pending("Error: EVP_PKEY_encrypt | " + string(ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr)));
    return {};
}

std::vector<unsigned char> encrypted(outlen);
```

Consider that `EVP_PKEY_encrypt()` might return a *negative* value for errors as well. You treat everything that is not zero as success. If it failed however, `outlen` might not be initialized properly, in which case it might hold a huge number which causes the constructor of `encrypted` to run out of memory, throwing the `std::bad_alloc`.

Comment: Yeah, i think you was right, could you check my code in Edit 2?

Comment: I don't see any error handling in edit 2; you check for the return values being `<= 0` but the `if`-statements are not doing anything.

Comment: Well i mean if all openssl errors etc are handled, i left handling empty because i would just add logging

Comment: Ok, now it looks like it should not cause a `std::bad_alloc` exception.